# Send XHR request from Chrome console to wamp localhost

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest, wamp, google-chrome-devtools

I tried to send a JSON via XHR request from Chrome console to localhost where is placed my handler.php
I set XHR url to *localhost/handler.php*, but it doesn't works. It was just appended to end of current url.

```
www.current-url.com/something/text/localhost/handler.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLs 101: If you're on a site "http://example.com/subdir", then here's how the various URL types get intrepreted:

```
relative:             foo.html                    -> http://example/subdir/foo.html
relative:             ../foo.html                 -> http://example.com/foo.html
relative:             ../otherdir/foo.html        -> http://example.com/otherdir/foo.html
local absolute:       /foo.html                   -> http://examle.com/foo.html
local relative:       google.com/hi/mom/foo.html  -> http://example.com/subdir/hi/mom/foo.html
local absolute:       /google.com/hi/mom/foo.html -> http://example.com/google.com/hi/mom/foo.html
universal absolute:   http://google.com/kittens   -> http://google.com/kittens
```

In other words, if you want a URL to be interpreted as some OTHER side, it has to be a "universal absolute" and include a complete url: `protocol://host/path`.

Comment: Thanks, it works :) but now I get Not allowed error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/handler.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access. Do you have any idea for this problem ? How I can fix it ?

Comment: you can't do ajax requests to "foreign" addresses, unless you've set the CORS header, exactly as the error says.

Comment: And how can I implement it to following code:var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/handler.php");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send(json_data);

Comment: you don't. there's nothing you can do on the client to override this. that'd make CORS protection useless. you have to have your server output the mentioned header.